# Can I transfer my question between Stack Exchange sites if it was off topic?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question a year ago on a Stack Exchange site, Server Fault, I was running out of time so I did not see that it was off topic, so it voted down, but later I got a badge of popular question (viewed more than 1000 times), I thought maybe if I could transfer that question with its answers (accepted or not), to another site like Stack Overflow so it could be useful and I am not voted down on that site any more.

Enlightenment please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, questions that are more than 60 days old cannot be migrated, even by moderators.